# grunt usemin and grunt filerev

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, grunt-usemin

I'm using grunt filerev and grunt usemin to replace all asset references in my jsp files. But i've one of the unique issues where the grunt task fails:

I've one of my jsp which includes the javascript as :

```
1.jsp
=====

....
   <script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/js/sample.js"/>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/js/example.js?config=1"/>
....
```

Notice the query parameter (config=1) in the above case. The grunt filerev and usemin correctly replaces the asset with it's revved name if it does not contain any query parameter.

In the above example, it correctly replaces the first asset reference but fails to replace the second one.

i.e the output looks like:

```
1.jsp
=======

...
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/js/sample.a1234asdf3.js"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/js/example.js?config=1"/>
...
```

I tried googling for any options to overcome this issue (i.e to achieve the correct replacement in the second case (asset referenced with query param)) but couldn't get much information.
Any idea as how to overcome this ? Am i missing any options associated with grunt filerev and grunt usemin ??

Comment: there are already have merge request for allow querystring in src attribute  
[https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-usemin/pull/443](https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-usemin/pull/443)  
but currunt status is "waiting".  

how about this way:  

    <!-- build:js js/example.js?config=1-->

Comment: @namxee: Thanks for your answer, looks like above pull request is merged but how do i install this version of grunt-usemin. npm install grunt-usemin --save-dev doesn't install this required version